# Changing a string into the name of a button

Tags: python, string, tkinter

Im trying to figure out how to change a string into a name of a `Button`.

For example if I had the string `self._name = 'self._prentice'`, I would like to make `self._prentice = tk.Button(master)`. I need to do it this way as the string could be any name and I need to create a way of storing this so I can later `pack` or `destroy` it.

I've tried using `exec`, however I could only get it to work for integers and not buttons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a function of a module from a string with the function's name in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python)

Comment: @glS it's indeed a duplicate but the one you link too is possibly not the best exemple...

Comment: If you need to create a dynamic number of buttons with different names, consider storing them in a single dictionary instead of as multiple attributes. Additional reading: [How do I create a variable number of variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/953482)

Comment: Suggest you read [_Why you don't want to dynamically create variables_](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html).

Comment: Whatever problem you're trying to solve, there are almost certainly better ways to solve it. We have an [xy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem here: you have problem "X" and think that "Y" is the solution so you ask about "Y". However, you should try to ask about "X" instead. Usually when people ask a question like this, the answer is to store the widgets in a dictionary, so that your "any name" is used as the key, and the widget is the value.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setattr`:

`setattr(self, '_prentice', tk.Button(master))`.

Comment: With a `self._name = '_prentice'`, a `setattr(self, self._name, tk.Button(master))` might be more useful to OP.

Answer (score -2):

In python, the instance variables of a class are stored in a dictionary, `self.__dict__`, so instead of

```
self._prentice = tk.Button(master)
```

you could write

```
self.__dict__['_prentice'] = tk.Button(master)
```

or, in your case

```
self.__dict__[self._name] = tk.Button(master)
```

Comment: It should be preferable to use `setattr` rather than directly changing `self.__dict__`.

Comment: Dont. Seriously dont. It bypasses all the attribute lookup rules and will break computed properties etc. The answer is `getatt(obj, name) / setattr(obj, name, value)`